# ISPConfig change "Document Root" for specific domain

Tags: ispconfig, ispconfig-3

How to change the `Document Root` for a specific domain/subdomain inside ISPConfig 3.

I need to point my subdomain to a different directory than the standard `client3` `web6` roots.

And in "ISPConfig 3" this field isn't editable, neither during creation nor afterwards.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, All I had to do is, once the domain was created, I had to navigate as below..

`Select that domain` > `Options` > `Apache Directives`

And paste the following line where the root of the domain/subdomain would be adjusted accordingly. I wanted to point the domain to rainloop installation which was outside the Default `Web Root` directory `/var/www/html`.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/rainloop/"
```

Have written this Q/A as a documentation as in-spite of it being so simple, this solution isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: for me only works on http schema ... when I want to access the site via https, it still relay on old path..

Comment: The Answer from Mohd Abdul Mujib still is correct, but today (ISPConfig Version 3.2.x) the Apache Directives are found in Sites > Options > Apache Directives there you can input what you need. i.e. Document Root "your/new/folder"

Answer (score -1):

Hey yeah you can put this as directive snippsel:

DocumentRoot {DOCROOT_CLIENT}/YOURNEWFOLDER

in complete that shows something like this in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/ in the lower, isp config put this in:

DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/client10/web72/web/YOURNEWFOLDER